# Swift3.0 Custom Row in Tableview returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I've been following a guide by Apple on their developer page, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html).

The following block of code in the file TableViewController is giving me some trouble

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CoinTableViewCell"
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CoinsTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
    }
    
    let coinrow = coins[indexPath.row]
    

    cell.rowLabel.text = coinrow.name // error on this line
    

    return cell
}
```

I'm getting a runtime error, occurring on the second last line of code, stating

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

I've found out using breakpoints that the value of `cell.rowLabel` is nil. However I can't work out why. The identifier for the custom row is "CoinTableViewCell". Any ideas what is going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you connected the outlet for rowLabel?

Comment: Yes I have, inside the custom controller for the cell

Comment: You are casting your cell to type `CoinsTableViewCell`. Yet, in your fatalError statement, you are calling it a `MealTableViewCell`. It could be that the `rowLabel` is defined in `MealTableViewCell` and not `CoinTableViewCell`.

Comment: Forgot to change the text from Apples sample code - however that is just a string error message, MealTableViewCell does not exist in my project. Nice pickup though!

Comment: `cell` can't be `nil`. If it was, the `fatalError` call would be made. Please clarify which value is really `nil` and clearly indicate which line is causing the error.

Comment: Looks like you're correct, thank you. I've updated the post with a screenshot of the debugging information, looks like rowLabel is nil

Comment: I think you should first disconnect the outlet of `rowLabel` and then reconnect in the custom  cell subclass `CoinsTableViewCell`

Comment: clear and reconnect your outlets and check what value is actually returning as of "coinrow"

Comment: You have not connected the `rowLabel` outlet to the `UILabel` in the cell in your storyboard.